# font-family (CSS)

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I'm working on a website for a client, and I would like to customize the font a little.

On this website:

http://unos.com/

There are several topics in the navigation menu, like: menu, locations, nutrition, email club, etc.

That is the font I want.
All I could find when inspecting page source was:

```
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

But this does not give the desired effect.

How can I get the font as is on the website above?

Also: I did try `font-family:cursive`, but this does not give me the desired result either.

I'm also trying to avoid using `CSS3` in case of older browsers. If it is the only way, though, then I can use the `font-face` easily enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in that navigation menu is not a font, but an [image](http://unos.com/images/navmenu2011.gif). If you don't want to use straight-up images, Google "font replacement" and you will find material that discusses how to replace "plain" text in your webpage with something more elaborate (for example, [see this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/typography-articles/a-web-designers-guide-to-font-replacement-methods/)).

Comment: I considered that, but I thought it would've been a different `<img>` tag for each option. But I see that you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the `<a>` elements use sprites for background images. [This graphic](http://unos.com/images/navmenu2011.gif). Not sure what font was used to made that though. Your guess is as good as mine.